# Integrating Tomcat in eclipse - server unable to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I successfully added tomcat 6 in Eclipse

But, when i am running my project, error pop-up is coming as follows:

Port 8080 required by apache-tomcat-6.0.36 at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

When i open localhost:8080, glassfish server is opening

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried renaming/changing the port?

Comment: Finally, i resolved my problem.

I used 'nestst -a -n -o'

Then, i checked the PID of process using port 8080,

I killed that process using taskmanager.

But, if anyone has a good way to achieve this. Please let me know.

Comment: See my answer. That's what I told. Either kill the other process or change the port number for tomcat, so that both the servers can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either kill your `GlassFish` server which is running or else, better, change the `port` number from `8080` to something else in your tomcat `server.xml`.

Something like this in your `server.xml` in the `conf` folder of `tomcat` installation directory.

```
<Connector port="8100" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... />
                 ^^^^ --> Changed from 8080 to another port number.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here both glassfish serves isrunning on the same port 8080.Tomcat default port is 8080.So change into another port.

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol=".....
 change it to
  <Connector port="8888" protocol=".....
```

You can see this file in `Tomcat 6.0\conf`

Answer (score 0):

In the server view (Window--> Show view --> Server) , you can change the port of the tomcat that eclipse is using:

[image]